Conditional Column Join in SQL
I have two tables as follow:
Table A:

Table B:

I'm trying to find a way to do conditional join on column such as

When TableA.Type = A then join with TableB.FruitTypeId = 7

When TableA.Type = B then join with TableB.FruitTypeId = 8

When TableA.Type = C then join with TableB.FruitTypeId = 1


Is there a way to do this?

This question is similar to: Conditional Join in DB2. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Please consider following these suggestions.

it is a bit annoying you dont put the create table and inserts

How To Get Answers To SQL Server Performance Questions
Please show your full DDL (the CREATE statements for the table and inserts of the data)

Sorry I was completely oblivious about not putting create table and insert, that link is my new bible now.

Consider using an intermediate mapping table that establishes the relationship between Table A types and Table B fruit types.

first thanks to Bob Klimes for producing the create table and inserts.
I have used union all, instead of case in the join.
This type of database design, I have had experience with this before,
is not ideal for performance.

                        print @@servername
                        SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
                        SET NOCOUNT OFF

    if object_id('tempdb..#tmpA') is not null
       drop table #tmpa

    if object_id('tempdb..#tmpB') is not null
       drop table #tmpb

    create table #tmpA(id int not null, type char(1) not null, value int not null)
   alter table #tmpA add constraint pkA primary key clustered(type,id)
    
    create table #tmpB(id int not null, FruitTypeId int not null , value varchar(10)not null)
    alter table #tmpB add constraint pkb primary key clustered(FruitTypeId,id)
    
    insert into #tmpA(id,type,value)
    values(1,'A',17),
    (2,'B',18),
    (3,'C',19),
    (4,'B',20),
    (5,'C',21)
    
    
    insert into #tmpB(id,FruitTypeId,value)
    values (1,7,'Apple'),
    (2,8,'Banana'),
    (3,7,'Apple'),
    (4,8,'Banana'),
    (5,1,'Durian')

SELECT  *
FROM    #tmpA a


SELECT  *
FROM    #tmpB b





SELECT  *
FROM    #tmpA a
inner join #tmpB b
on case when a.type = 'A' then 7
        when a.type = 'B' then 8
        when a.type = 'C' then 1 end = b.FruitTypeId



SELECT  *
FROM    #tmpA a
inner join #tmpB b
on b.FruitTypeId = 7
and a.type = 'A'

union all

SELECT  *
FROM    #tmpA a
inner join #tmpB b
on b.FruitTypeId = 8
and a.type = 'B'

union all

SELECT  *
FROM    #tmpA a
inner join #tmpB b
on b.FruitTypeId = 1
and a.type = 'C'



--=======================================
-- cross apply suggesttion by erik darling
--========================================
SELECT
    *
FROM #tmpA AS a
CROSS APPLY
(
     SELECT
        B.*
     FROM #tmpB AS b
     WHERE b.FruitTypeId = 7
     AND   a.type = 'A'
     
     UNION ALL
     
     SELECT
        B.*
     FROM #tmpB AS b
     WHERE b.FruitTypeId = 8
     AND   a.type = 'B'
     
     UNION ALL
     
     SELECT
        B.*
     FROM #tmpB AS b
     WHERE b.FruitTypeId = 1
     AND   a.type = 'C'
) AS b;



You can simplify this with just one access to #tmpA: fiddlin

amazing! added it to the answer with thanks

The first, and second statements seem to be OK, but the third and fourth are way to complex for this... (see: https://dbfiddle.uk/JHuhNtgL )

This can be accomplished using a case statement on one side of join clause.
setup test schema and data
 create table #tmpA(id int, type char(1), value int)
    
    
    create table #tmpB(id int, FruitTypeId int, value varchar(10))
    
    
    insert into #tmpA(id,type,value)
    values(1,'A',17),
    (2,'B',18),
    (3,'C',19),
    (4,'B',20),
    (5,'C',21)
    
    
    insert into #tmpB(id,FruitTypeId,value)
    values (1,7,'Apple'),
    (2,8,'Banana'),
    (3,7,'Apple'),
    (4,8,'Banana'),
    (5,1,'Durian')

Here is example query with case in join clause. When type is A case will return 7, type is B case will return 8, and type is C case will return 1
SELECT  *
FROM    #tmpA a
inner join #tmpB b
on case when a.type = 'A' then 7
        when a.type = 'B' then 8
        when a.type = 'C' then 1 end = b.FruitTypeId


it works but the performance normally sucks - depends if that is important or not

agreed @stephenmorris.  here is a reasonable article discussing this https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/7664/sql-case-statement-in-join/

Why not just replace TableA.Type with FruitTypeId directly?
select * 
from TableA ; 

+----+-------------+-------+
| ID | FruitTypeId | Value |
+----+-------------+-------+
|  1 |           7 |    17 |
|  2 |           8 |    18 |
|  3 |           7 |    19 |
|  4 |           8 |    20 |
|  5 |           1 |    21 |
+----+-------------+-------+

No "extra" mapping required.
If, for some reason, you do need that extra mapping, then you need an extra table to hold it in:
select * 
from A2BMapping 

+------+------+
| a_id | b_id |
+------+------+
| A    |    7 |
| B    |    8 |
| C    |    1 |
+------+------+

select TableA.*, TableB.* 
from TableA A 
inner join A2BMapping A2B 
   on A.Type = A2B.a_id 
inner join TableB B 
   on A2B.b_id = B.FruitTypeId

+----+------+-------+----+-------------+--------+
| Id | Type | Value | Id | FruitTypeId | Value  | 
+----+------+-------+----+-------------+--------+
|  1 | A    |    17 |  1 |           7 | Apple  |
|  2 | B    |    18 |  2 |           8 | Banana |
|  3 | A    |    19 |  3 |           7 | Apple  |
|  4 | B    |    20 |  4 |           8 | Banana |
|  5 | C    |    21 |  5 |           1 | Durian |
+----+------+-------+----+-------------+--------+


Why this downvoted ?@Phil meant that Create seperate mapping table or Denormalise and put FruitTypeId in Table A.Depednign upon volume of data and data type denormalisation process is not bad
